# Put the contents of listbox into excel cells (cells not defined)

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a listbox which has 3 items in it and I want to loop through the items in the listbox and put them into individual cells. The cells that I want the items to be put into will start 5 columns down from the last cell with information in it: For example: If the last cell with data in it was C5 then I would want the data to be put in the cells at C10 (ending at C13 because there are only 3 items). Below shows the code for finding the location of the last cell and then finding the cell which is 5 down from it:

```
 LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow + 5, "E").Value = 'list box items'
```

How ever how would I get the list box items to populate in these cells. listbox is called nameList

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).offset(5).resize(3).value = me.nameList.List
```